# Dados não persistem ao salvar com caixa de diálogo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho uma lista em que quero selecionar o item alterar um campo da tabela produto e salvar no banco através de um dialog. Sabendo que um produto possui vários históricos , ou seja o relacionamento é de OneToMany . Ocorre que o item não está sendo alterado. Exite algum problema em enviar o item de uma lista de historicos e alterar o campo do produto salvando o historico?

Segue o código do xhtml da lista:

```
<p:dataTable id="historicosTable"
                value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.lazyModel}" var="historico"
                style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="#{msg.nenhum_tecnico}"

                paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="5" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(#{msg.pagina} {currentPage} #{msg.de} {totalPages}) - (#{msg.registro} {startRecord} #{msg.a} {endRecord}) - Total ({totalRecords} #{msg.registros})"
                styleClass="mystyle" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 30" lazy="true" editable="true"
                editMode="cell">

                <f:facet id="header" name="header">
               Previsão de Vendas
            </f:facet>


                <p:column headerText=" Codigo do Produto"
                    sortBy="#{historico.produto.codigoProduto}"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

                    <p:commandLink value="#{historico.produto.codigoProduto}"
                        update=":userDetailForm:display" oncomplete="userDialog.show()"
                        title="View">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{historico}"
                            target="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
```

segue o codigo xhtml do dialog :`

```
<p:dialog header="Alterar Previsão" widgetVar="userDialog"
            resizable="false" id="userDlg">
            <h:form id="userDetailForm">
                <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="4" cellpadding="4"
                    style="margin:0 auto;">


                    <p:outputLabel value="Ultimo Ano:" for="ultimoAno" />
                    <p:inputText id="ultimoAno"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.anoAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.ultimaQuantidade}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="terceiro Mês:" for="terceiroMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="terceiroMes"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.terceiroMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade4" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade4"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.terceiraQuantidade}" />


                    <p:outputLabel value="segundo Mês:" for="segundoMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="segundoMes"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.segundoMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade3" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade3"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.segundaQuantidade}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Primeiro mês:" for="primeiroMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="primeiroMes"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.primeiroMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade1" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade1"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.primeiraQuantidade}" />




                    <h:outputText value="Previsao:"></h:outputText>

                    <h:inputText
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.produto.quantidadeRecente}" />


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="alterar" value="Alterar"
                            update=":frmPesquisa:historicosTable" process="@this"
                            oncomplete="tratarAssociacao(args)"
                            action="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.alterarPrevisao}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>



@Named
```

@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaPrevisaoBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Inject
private Historicos previsoes;

@Inject
@UsuarioLogado
private Usuario usuario;

@Inject
private Familias familias;

@Inject
private Linhas linhas;

private Linha linhaSelecionada;

private Familia familiaSelecionada;

private List<Linha> linhasDaEmpresa;

private List<Familia> familiasDaEmpresa;

private List<Historico> listaDePrevisoes;

private Historico previsaoSelecionada;

@Inject
private CadastroHistoricoService cadastroHistoricoService;

private PrevisaoLazyList lazyPrevisoes;

public List<Historico> getPrevisoes() {
    return listaDePrevisoes;
}

public void inicializar() {
    if (FacesUtil.isNotPostback()) {
        lazyPrevisoes = new PrevisaoLazyList(previsoes, linhaSelecionada);
        familiasDaEmpresa = familias.carregaFamilia(usuario.getEmpresa().getCodigo());
        if (this.familiaSelecionada != null) {
            carregarLinhasComFamilia();

        }

    }
}

public void pesquisar() {

    lazyPrevisoes = new PrevisaoLazyList(previsoes, linhaSelecionada);

}

public void carregarLinhasComFamilia() {

    linhasDaEmpresa = linhas.carregaLinhasComFamilia(familiaSelecionada.getCodigo());
}

public void carregarListaHistoricos() {
    listaDePrevisoes = previsoes.carregaHistorico();
}

public void excluir() {
    previsoes.remover(previsaoSelecionada);
    this.listaDePrevisoes.remove(previsaoSelecionada);
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Provisão " + " excluída com sucesso.");
}

public void alterarPrevisao() {

    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Previsão " + previsaoSelecionada.getProduto().getDescricao());

    cadastroHistoricoService.salvar(previsaoSelecionada);
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {

    Historico hist = ((Historico) event.getObject());
    System.out.println(hist.toString());
    //cadastroHistoricoService.salvar(hist);

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Produto Edited", ((Historico) event.getObject()).getProduto().getDescricao());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public Historico getPrevisaoSelecionada() {
    return previsaoSelecionada;
}

public void setPrevisaoSelecionada(Historico previsaoSelecionada) {
    this.previsaoSelecionada = previsaoSelecionada;
}

public Linha getLinhaSelecionada() {
    return linhaSelecionada;
}

public Familia getFamiliaSelecionada() {
    return familiaSelecionada;
}

public void setLinhaSelecionada(Linha linhaSelecionada) {
    this.linhaSelecionada = linhaSelecionada;
}

public void setFamiliaSelecionada(Familia familiaSelecionada) {
    this.familiaSelecionada = familiaSelecionada;
}

public List<Linha> getLinhasDaEmpresa() {
    return linhasDaEmpresa;
}

public List<Familia> getFamiliasDaEmpresa() {
    return familiasDaEmpresa;
}

public PrevisaoLazyList getLazyModel() {
    return lazyPrevisoes;
}
```

SEGUE O CODIGO DO SERVICE

```
public class CadastroHistoricoService implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Historicos historicos;

@Transactional
public void salvar(Historico historico) {

    System.out.println(historico.getQuantidade());

    try {
        this.historicos.guardar(historico);
    } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {

        throw new NegocioException(FacesUtil.getMensagemI18n("concorrencia_familia"));

    }

}
```

}

CÓDIGO DE HISTÓRICOS

```
public class Historicos implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Historico porId(Long id) {

    return manager.find(Historico.class, id);

}

@Inject
@UsuarioLogado
private Usuario usuario;

public void guardar(Historico historico) {

    manager.merge(historico);
}
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo da classe `CadastroHistoricoService`? E o que faz aquele código comentado, `cadastroHistoricoService.salvar(hist)` no código?

Comment: Editei colocando mo código do service e o comentário foi outra tentativa de salvar o dados utilizando cellEdit, que não salvou também.

Comment: E o que tem dentro do históricos? Estou procurando o local onde você usa algum framework de persistência (se for o caso) para salvar a informação no banco de dados.

Comment: da uma olhada na tela que  ajuda mais https://snag.gy/HF1pmt.jpg

Comment: A imagem ainda não fornece informações para resolver seu problema, creio que seja o seu código o problema (aliás, é mais negócio comprar um AMD Ryzen 1700 que um Intel i7 :) )

Comment: coloquei também o codigo de historicos

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60770/discussion-between-dherik-and-user2509556).

Comment: Habilita o log no persistence e olha a query que ta sendo gerada. Caso use eclipselink ´<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
 <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>´

Comment: coloquei la no chat

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no `process` do commandbutton. Com `@this` o único dado que está sendo submetido é o próprio botão. Substitua por `@form`.